# Sound crackling/popping in Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-9.10, audio

I seem to be experiencing huge amounts of sound poping/crackling on my linux install.  The sound preferences are way different than 9.04 so I can't test out other drivers for audio.  Any suggestions please :(

Answer (score 1):

These are the links I will refer to in the rest of the post:

```
1. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/301755
2. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/410948
```

Hi. I experienced a similar problem in ubuntu karmic 64-bit. Apparently it has to do with problems in the alsa drivers and kernel of linux and not in the pulseaudio server. This also means that the folks maintaining pulseaudio for ubuntu have little chance to intervene on this.

There are a number of workarounds that (partially) solve the problem, but for each configuration the workaround seems to be a bit different. Sometimes you need to tell pulseaudio to ignore driver's information, sometimes you need to tweak the alsamixer configuration.

[Bug #1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/301755) is a thread that seems to deal with your problem (it has status "fix committed") but in my case, for example, the problem started from [Bug #2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/410948) and the crackling sound came into the scene only when I modified the alsamixer parameters. Luckily in my case it only happens when the volume is almost off, so I didn't bother search for a definitive fix.

I am afraid you will have to dig a bit into launchpad to find which of the many bugs related to this matches your situation.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me,  I updated my Linux Mint RC1 review as I was having the same trouble. The example is in the update section at the bottom of the post.  There is also a link to the original article and video.
[link text](http://www.worldoweb.co.uk/2009/linux-hail-helena)]

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and it was electrical interference. Try shielding or moving your amp/speakers away from your computer.